# Вытащить уникальную дату из mySQL

Tags: php, mysqli

В таблице mySQL есть id_таблицы ,  дата_приёма , id_пациента, uid_врача. Каждый врач каждый день может принимать несколько пациентов. Например 2017.06.23 - 2 приёма, 2017.06.24 - 1 приём и т д.

На странице врача нужно вывести это в таблице HTML. Глядя на это чтоб бухгалтер сразу же знал сколько приёмов за каждую дату у врача. 
В виде **Дата-количество приёмов** и всё. Какой запрос "сочинить" ради этого ? 
Сейчас делаю так

```
<?php
$result100 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT num, prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem 
WHERE doctor_uid=$uidforfaq GROUP BY num, prdate ;")  or  die("<p>Не удается выбрать запись из базы данных</p>". mysqli_error($con));
$rowcount2 = mysqli_num_rows($result100);
?>
```

Здесь num ид таблицы, prdate дата приёма
Но он мне выводит все приёмы за все время. А надо чтоб было **ДАТА-КОЛИЧЕСТВО ПРИЁМОВ...**. Может быть для вывода даты сделать отдельный запрос. Тогда не знаю как обьяснить mySQL чтоб он сортировал именно по этой дате. Короче не могу ничего сообразить. Подскажите пожалуйста !

Comment: `SELECT count(num) as cnt, prdate FROM priem 
WHERE doctor_uid=$uidforfaq GROUP BY prdate ;`

Comment: У Вас точно поле prdate - это поле даты, а не даты-времени? проверьте, используя `GROUP BY DATE(prdate), ...`

Comment: да это поле даты.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь вам это поможет

```
SELECT COUNT(`num`) AS `num`, DATE_FORMAT(`prdate`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `prdate` 
FROM priem WHERE doctor_uid = `11` GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`prdate`, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Алексей Шиманский, sanmai, Shnur Спасибо Вам за ответы дорогие друзья ! Но он показывает количество приёмов 1. А на самом деле кол-во приёмов 2. Он по моему сортирует по дате. Так как за ОДИН день два приёма. Может я неправильно вывожу на страницу. Совсем забыл сказать что вывожу я так <?php echo $rowcount2 ;  ?>

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT doctor_uid, prdate, COUNT(*) FROM priem 
    WHERE doctor_uid=$uidforfaq GROUP BY prdate
```

И так по каждому врачу. Вы же всё равно будете таблицы отдельно показывать для удобства - разделять выборку на части не нужно будет.